# Render variables printed by {{ dump(user) }} in a template?

Tags: 8, theming

I have the following code in node.html.twig.

```
{{ dump(user) }}
```

I get this output.

```
object(Drupal\Core\Session\AccountProxy)#523 (4) {
["account":protected]=>
object(Drupal\Core\Session\UserSession)#91 (16) {
["uid":protected]=>
string(1) "1"
["roles":protected]=>
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(13) "authenticated"
  [1]=>
  string(13) "administrator"
}
["access":protected]=>
string(10) "1513942493"
["name"]=>
string(5) "admin"
["preferred_langcode":protected]=>
string(2) "en"
["preferred_admin_langcode":protected]=>
NULL
["mail":protected]=>
string(18) "noreply@imi.org.uk"
["timezone":protected]=>
string(13) "Europe/Berlin"
["langcode"]=>
string(2) "en"
["pass"]=>
string(55) "$S$E7IRVipuFHHectBpj8GkGZGPHlFWNQKG9ydDoRpwBDcCbzklpVaj"
["status"]=>
string(1) "1"
["created"]=>
string(10) "1513920795"
```

I want to render value of `["created"]=>string(10) "1513920795"` and `["uid":protected]=>string(1) "1"`. What is the syntax or code to output them from the template?

Comment: All variables that can be rendered either need to be a plain value (such as a variable injected to the template via a preprocess hook) or a render array (like a field). Both are done as `{{ variable }}` or `{{ content.variable }}` respectively. The easiest way to inspect variables is to use xdebug and inspect them with a preprocess node hook in the themes `.theme` file, or use Twig XDebug to set a breakpoint in the twig template.

Answer (score 1):

You can just get the user ID and when the account was created respectively with `{{ user.id }}` and `{{ user.created }}`. With `{{ user.created | date("d F Y") }}` you print the timestamp with the date format you specify.

Consider `user` as an object. You can access all the values the same way.

See also the [Twig documentation](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/).

Comment: I actually want to render other variables too when i debug this way. how do i do it? if i want to render other variables like timezone, langcode etc?

Comment: thank you for your answer.  {{ dump(date) }} also gives me an output with string(..) " " I dont understand. I just want to print the raw value of the date in the front end. how do i do it?

Comment: @IronButterfly That is a different question. It's not that because you are asking about two values taken from the user object, you will get an answer for every value a user object has.

Comment: Just use xdebug to see what your variables are, it will be less hassle.